# How to unregister sensor (accelerometer) in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, sensors

I already register ACCELEROMETER sensor using service to run in background but i want to unregister ACCELEROMETER sensor using broadcast receiver by clicking notification action(Button Click)...i search a lot but didn't get 
thanks for help... :)

Answer (score 0):

here is a Method for Unregister sensor I have used in my code and its working proper :

```
   private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // angle between the magnetic north direction
        // 0=North, 90=East, 180=South, 270=West
        float azimuth = event.values[0];
        compassView.updateData(azimuth);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (sensor != null) {
        sensorService.unregisterListener(mySensorEventListener);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ans..sensorService.unregisterListener(mySensorEventListener); but i want to access this method in Broadcast receiver